# accepts_nested_attributes with nested form and select field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Facing a issue in select tag with accepts_nested_attributes_for with has many and explicit foreign key.  I am not able to get the associated values listed.

**`Models`**

```
class PlantPlate < Plate
  has_many :unit_plates, :foreign_key => 'parent_id', :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :unit_plates, :allow_destroy => true
end

class UnitPlate < Plate
  belongs_to :plant_plate, :foreign_key => 'parent_id'
end
```

**`View`**
/plant_plates/_form.html.erb

```
<%= nested_form_for([ :admin, @plant_plate ]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :unit_plates  do |unit_plate| %>
    <%= unit_plate.collection_select :parent_id, UnitPlate.all,:id,:name %>
<%end
<%end%>
```

**I want to list all the associated unit plates in select tag** .  But somehow now able to do that with this select tag.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try out `form_for` instead:

```
<%= form_for([:admin, @plant_plate]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :unit_plate do |unit_plate| %>
    <%= unit_plate.collection_select :parent_id, UnitPlate.all, :id, :name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: i am using the nested form gem, so i need this nested_form_for

Comment: Can you please share some more details about what kind of error raising? or some output from your development.log, without more code hard to help

Answer (score 0):

Try out using basic f.select:

```
<%= f.select :parent_id, options_from_collection_for_select(UnitPlate.all, 'id', 'name') %>
```